# Refactoring this piece of code - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I've just written this piece that I need help in refactoring because I don't think there should be that much logic inside a view?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xMim.png (code block wasn't displaying right so I created a screenshot and uploaded to imgur.)

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
<% if @match.creator == current_user or @match.opponent == current_user %>
  <% if Result.where(user_id: current_user.id, match_id: @match.id).exists? %>
    You've submitted your results. thank you.
  <% else %>
    <%= render('results/form') %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  you don't have access to this.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe this question would be more suitable for [codereview Stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: A bit hard without more context. How does your controller look? When is this supposed to be rendered?

Comment: You know you could copy/paste the code block as text into your problem statement and make it easier to see rather than using a screen shot on a remote image site? And there's not really enough context here to determine a reasonable refactoring. At first blush, I'd say the logic could be in the controller and do the render from there mostly, but without knowing the controller interaction or what else the view is doing, hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I would try to resolve that pre-view. Consider making a before callback to verify the creator is a particular user - if it is, do nothing, otherwise redirect to restricted access page.

```
before_filter :authorize_creator, only: [:show]

def show
  @result = blah blah
end

private

  def authorize_creator
      redirect_to blah_path unless [@match.creator, @match.opponent].include?(current_user)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect answer. I also added <%= render('results/form') unless @result %> to the view to make it work how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Trust your instincts; there should definitely not be that much logic in a view. Also, there should NEVER be an explicit call to the database embedded in the view. The controller should just be concerned with what to render or redirect, and maybe very simple initializing. More involved logic can go in helpers or decorators. (Decorators aren't in rails by default, but the Draper gem and others make it easy to include them.)

A 'fat controller' way to clean up the view might be something like:

```
def show
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  if [@match.creator, @match.opponent].include?(current_user)
    @results_submitted = Result.where(user_id: current_user.id, match_id: @match.id).exists?
  else
    render text: "You don't have access to this", status: 403 and return
  end
end
```

The idea is to precompute things for the view, and even eliminate conditionals from the view if you can. You also might want to use a gem like Pundit or CanCanCan to help control access to matches.